# Multiple constraints spring validation

Tags: java, spring-validator

I am using spring to validate a form. The model for the form is similar to this:

```
public class FormModel {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ImageSizeConstraint
    private MultipartFile image;

}
```

The '@ImageSizeConstraint' is a custom constraint. What I want is for the @NotNull to be evaluated first and if this evaluates to false, not to evaluate @ImageSizeConstraint.

If this is not possible, I will have to check for null in the custom constraint as well. Which is not a problem, but I would like to seperate the concerns (not null / image size / image / aspectratio / etc).

Comment: How about coding the `NotNull` **in** your custom constraint?

Comment: Possible, but I'd like to separate the concerns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use constraints grouping and group sequences to define the validation order. According to [JSR-303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) (part *3.5. Validation routine*):

> Unless ordered by group sequences, groups can be validated in no
>   particular order. This implies that the validation routine can be run
>   for several groups in the same pass.

As Hibernate Validator [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#chapter-groups) says:

> In order to implement such a validation order you just need to define
>   an interface and annotate it with @GroupSequence, defining the order
>   in which the groups have to be validated (see Defining a group
>   sequence). If at least one constraint fails in a sequenced group, none
>   of the constraints of the following groups in the sequence get
>   validated.

First, you have to define constraint groups and apply them to the constraints:

```
public interface CheckItFirst {}

public interface ThenCheckIt {}

public class FormModel {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotNull(groups = CheckItFirst.class)
    @ImageSizeConstraint(groups = ThenCheckIt.class)
    private MultipartFile image;
}
```

And then, as constraints are evaluated in no particular order, regardless of which groups they belong to (`Default` group too), you have to create [@GroupSequence](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#section-defining-group-sequences) for your `image` field constraints groups.

```
@GroupSequence({ CheckItFirst.class, ThenCheckIt.class })
public interface OrderedChecks {}
```

You can test it with

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<FormModel>> constraintViolations =
                            validator.validate(formModel, OrderedChecks.class);
```

To apply this validation in Spring MVC Controller methods, you may use the [@Validated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) annotation, which can specify the validation groups for method-level validation:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/processFormModel")
public String processFormModel(@Validated(OrderedChecks.class) FormModel formModel) {
    <...>
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is nice to add that for Spring MVC the controller should use the @Validated({CheckItFirst.class, ThenCheckIt.class}) to use this.

Comment: Spring MVC controller example added. Although Hibernate validator seems to maintain the @Validated arguments order in validation routine, you should use the sequence, as JSR-303 says it's the only way to define the validation order.

Answer (score 3):

Easy just return true for isValid if image is null for your custom constraint.
Read the specification of [JSR-303](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303), you will see that this is normal behaviour and it makes sense as there is "NotNull".